# Unable to build Appium server since it fails to findNodeInCurrentFileSystem

Tags: java, node.js, appium

I am unable to build the Appium Server using this standard line `appiumDriverLocalService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();`

I get the following error message

```
io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: Invalid server instance exception has occured: There is no installed nodes! Please install node via NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium#using-node-js) or download and install Appium app (http://appium.io/downloads.html)

    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findNodeInCurrentFileSystem(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:184)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.checkAppiumJS(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:345)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:425)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:358)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:86)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:82)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: /Users/deepak/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules
rm: /tmp/deepak.start.74839: No such file or directory

    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findNodeInCurrentFileSystem(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:185)
    ... 29 more
```

*I have edited a few unnecessary TestNG lines to make it more readable.

I thought this was an issue with my node installation and I have re-installed node and currently the default node version in my local setup (Mac OS) is `v14.16.0`. But still I see an IOException for Node version  `v12.18.3`.

Does anyone have a solution for this? I have been stuck on this problem the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by adding the AppiumPath to the AppiumServiceBuilder

`serviceBuilder.withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/bin/appium")`

I think adding Node path or Appium path should be a standard. But how to force user to not forget this setup in their local or on the cloud?? This needs to be solved.